# How to make an actual copy of a struct (not a pointer)

Tags: c

This program uses an external file known as island.txt, and builds a linked list out of every line items. The problem is, as of this writing, I cannot copy the struct properly, it merely does a pointer to the current struct which is created. Can you guys get this program to print "**Result: Success!!!**"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/**
 * The data format of an island defined within a linked-list format
*/
typedef struct island {
    char * name;
    char * opens;
    char * closes;
    struct island * next;
} island;
/**
 *  The island create method 
*/
island * create ( char * name ){
    island * country = malloc(sizeof(island)); // Allocate a memory on the heap for the country
    country->name = strdup(name); // Allocate a memory on the heap for the name
    country->opens = "6:00 AM";
    country->closes = "11:00 PM";
    country->next = NULL;  
    free(country);
    return country;
}
/**
 * Automatically link islands togerther forming a link list on-new-line event
*/
void autoLink( char * country_name, char * file_name ){
    FILE * islands; // Define islands as a file  
    islands = fopen(file_name, "r");
    island * start_country = NULL; // An island variable to record the 1st item of the linked list
    island * country = NULL; // The next country item of an island
    island * previously_created_country = NULL;
    if(islands == NULL){
        perror("Error opening the file");
    } 
    else{
        char previous_country_name[80]; // The previous island name
        fgets(previous_country_name, 80, islands);
        while(fgets(country_name, 80, islands) != NULL){
            country = create(country_name);
            if(start_country == NULL){ // When starting the loop the next country is the start (1st country)
                start_country = country;  
            }
            else{  
                previously_created_country = create(previous_country_name);               
                previously_created_country->next = country;
                printf("\nThe current name is: %s", country_name);
                printf("Country name inside struct: %s", country->name);
                printf("The previously created country name inside the struct: %s", previously_created_country->name);
                printf("The previous name is: %s", previous_country_name);
                if(strcmp(country_name, country->name)){
                    printf("*****Result: Country name error!!!*****\n");
                }
                if(strcmp(previously_created_country->name, previous_country_name)){
                    printf("*****Result: Previous Country name error!!!*****\n");
                }
                if(!(strcmp(country_name, country->name) && strcmp(country_name, country->name))){
                    printf("*****Result: Success!!!*****\n");
                }
            }
            strcpy(previous_country_name, country_name);                    
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Starting point
*/
int main () {
    char name[80]; // The name of a given island
    char file_name[30] = "islands.txt";
    autoLink(name, file_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the islands.txt file content:

```
Haiti
Anguilla
Antigua and Barbuda
Aruba
The Bahamas
Barbados
Bonaire
British Virgin Islands
Cayman Islands
Cuba
Curaçao
Dominica
Dominican Republic
Federal Dependencies of Venezuela
Grenada
Guadeloupe
Jamaica
Martinique
Montserrat
Navassa Island
Nueva Esparta
Puerto Rico
Saba
San Andrés and Providencia
Saint Barthélemy
Saint Kitts and Nevis
Saint Lucia
Saint Martin
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
Sint Eustatius
Sint Maarten
Trinidad and Tobago
Turks and Caicos Islands
United States Virgin Islands
```

Comment: Please boil this down to a [mcve] and highlight which line(s) you are talking about. I have no idea where you are attempting to copy and fail doing so

Comment: Why do you free the island before you add it to the list?

Comment: `free(country);return country;` cannot be correct in any case, you are returning a dangling pointer

Comment: You've got a lot of bad habits going on here. Consider `char *file_name = "islands.txt";` in the future. That way you cannot botch the size. Buffer overflow bugs are extremely common in C and you do not want to make your life any more difficult than it already is. You *only* need to declare the size if you want to change that value or append to it.

Comment: `perror("Error opening the file");` is good, but `perror(file_name)` is better.

Comment: I agree with @UnholySheep. In island * create() method you delete all the data by issuing free(country) command.

Comment: To copy a struct, you can use `=` or `memcpy` or `memmove`.  I don't really see how the code given relates to the question in the title.

Comment: @tadman. I merely wanted a quick working example of linking list items based on a file. You are right, char * file_name = "islands.txt" doesn't assume the file name size.

Comment: It's little things like that which can trip you up hard later, like if your filename got to be 30 characters long. Always presume you're going to make a mistake at some point in the future and be kind to your future self!

Comment: Note: With `while(fgets(country_name, 80, islands) != NULL){ country = create(country_name);`, `country->name` certainly has a `'\n'` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create` function:

```
island * create ( char * name ){
    island * country = malloc(sizeof(island)); // Allocate a memory on the heap for the country
    country->name = strdup(name); // Allocate a memory on the heap for the name
    country->opens = "6:00 AM";
    country->closes = "11:00 PM";
    country->next = NULL;  
    free(country);      // <---- BAD
    return country;
}
```

After you finish populating your object, you `free` it and return the freed pointer.  That memory is no longer value as a result of beeing freed, and attempting to use a pointer to freed memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Get rid of the `free` in this function.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it is that one line of code I've carried over to a previous test. It works now, thanks.